# SQL Server Failover Cluster Setup Report

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, windows-clustering

Purpose: to find all the SQL Server Failover Cluster installation details for an existing cluster setup. I am trying to document the process for disaster recovery purposes and recreate a mirrored setup on a different group of servers.
(SQL Server 2012)

I am looking for a way to generate a report of all the setup details pertaining to the initial installation of a SQL Server Failover Cluster. Something akin to the SQL Discovery report that details all installed SQL Server features.

In this case, I'd like a report that shows all the details chosen when going through the initial setup wizard for the initial SQL Cluster setup. A report that shows the features selected, instance names, disk assignment, network configuration, etc. Just a summary of every section of the install wizard would be perfect. The Cluster Manager does not display all of the information I need.

Does such a thing exist? If I can't auto generate a report. Is there a log file somewhere that would detail the initial setup?

I have scoured the internet, but there are just too many keywords to return concise results. I'm looking for details of the SQL Cluster setup, not the Windows Cluster setup. I've had my fill of irrelevant articles, and I'm turning to the Stack Overflow community for help!

EDIT:
This query as provided some insight, but it's lacking. I'm looking for something more complete.

```
SELECT   
    SERVERPROPERTY('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS') AS ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS,
    SERVERPROPERTY('MachineName') AS MachineName,  
    SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName') AS ServerName,  
    SERVERPROPERTY('Collation') AS Collation,  
    SERVERPROPERTY('IsClustered') AS IsClustered
```

Also, these catalog views have provided some insight.

> **sys.dm_server_services, sys.configurations, sys.dm_server_registry, sys.dm_server_services, sys.dm_os_cluster_nodes, sys.servers**

Comment: In what way is this related to programming? Stackoverflow is a dedicated to questions related to programming - please keep questions [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and consider asking on a more appropriate [Stack Exchange Site](http://stackexchange.com/sites)

Comment: Since when are SQL questions not relevant on Stack Overflow? I use stack overflow all the time to find SQL and SQL Server related information. According to Stack Overflow stats, there have been 728 SQL-Server related questions , 443 database questions, 1215 SQL questions asked this week. I have found numerous other SQL statements that provide bits and pieces of this information. I assumed there was a SQL expert somewhere in the SOF community that could help me a comprehensive query.

Comment: I didn't state that SQL questions aren't relevant on SO - but only in the context of programming. I accept that there may be questions regarding SQL that aren't at all related to programming but that's no reason to disregard the SO policy: [On Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Have you tried to ask your question on http://dba.stackexchange.com ? I'm sure there you will find plenty of SQL experts.

Comment: There is a robust and active SQL community here at SO. There is a huge selection of questions even dedicated to Management Studio. (Just check the tags section if you don't believe me) If a fully UI driven SQL management tool is relevant then I'm sure a request for SQL queries and Log file locations is relevant. I have actually found a number of the answers to my questions on other stack overflow posts. I just don't have the full picture. I'll post what I have found. Maybe that will help someone else in the future. If you don't know the answer that's fine. I appreciate your input.